# C-Project: how can I get the dependent DLL file from Sonatype Nexus repository?

Tags: maven, jenkins, nexus

I start the build for c-project with jenkins and then in post process I deploy the dll files in sonatyp-nexus repo. It works fine, but now, how can I get the dependent DLL file from Sonatyp-Nexus repo in my local repo, there are C projects (not Java) tool Visual Studio 2010 and 2012. there a solution/idea (powershel or...)?

I deploy the dll files (C project) in Nexus with this maven goal:

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=<group-id> \
  -DartifactId=<artifact-id> \
  -Dversion=<version> \
  -Dpackaging=<type-of-packaging> \
  -Dfile=<path-to-file> \
  -DrepositoryId=<id-to-map-on-server-section-of-settings.xml> \
  -Durl=<url-of-the-repository-to-deploy>
```

I have created for c project a maven pom.xml, where does nothing...

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a dependency to the pom.xml with the coordinates of your dll.

For any other tool usage you can either use the REST API or even easier just to a wget/curl call to download the file. They are avaiable via straight forward normal HTTP.

You can even just browse your Nexus repositories and groups. E.g. Look at 
https://oss.sonatype.org/#view-repositories

to see all the repositories on OSSRH. E.g. the releases repository has a lot of components and you can just browse it:

https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/

And you can download any file (e.g. a random one) including dll files or whatever.

```
wget https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/repositories/releases/content/aero/m-click/mcpdf/0.2.1/mcpdf-0.2.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

Comment: thx.. yes that's what I intended, for me as a Java developer is ok but the problem is the C developer must then also install Maven... I thought maybe it's possible without Maven e.g. a powershell script migrate into Visual Studio.....